# Evaluate absolute expression in a probability density function

Tags: probability-theory, absolute-value

From my understanding:

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ $e^{{-(-\sqrt{y})^2/2}}$ |-$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}$| = $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ $e^{y / 2}$ $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}$

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ $e^{{-(\sqrt{y})^2/2}}$ |$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}$| = $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ $e^{-y / 2}$ $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}$

If so,

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ $e^{{-(-\sqrt{y})^2/2}}$ |-$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}$| + $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ $e^{{-(\sqrt{y})^2/2}}$ |$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}$| $\neq$ $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sqrt{y}}$ $e^{-y/2}$

Consequently, I can't understand how the highlighted equality in the following text could be derived. Could someone please explain? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: In your first line, you wrote $-(-\sqrt{y})^2 = y$. This is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$e^{-(-\sqrt y)^{2}/2}=e^{-y/2}$ not $e^{y/2}$.

When you square, the inside minus sign  goes away and the outside minus sign remains.

Comment: Ah, thanks for your clear answer, @Kavi. Could you also please confirm $g^{-1}(y)$ = -$\sqrt{y}$ because $A_1$ contains negative values?